# Not able to insert normalizer in mapping Elasticsearch 6.1.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping, normalization, lowercase

I had trying to insert the following mapping in the the index to support the search feature.

Index setting :

```
url: PUT http:/localhost:9200/indexname

{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "normalizer": {
                "my_normalizer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mappings :

```
url: PUT http:/localhost:9200/indexname/typename/_mapping

{
    "org-5-table": {
        "properties": {

            "GroupName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Createdby": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "GroupUser": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "UpdatedDateTime": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "GroupMessage": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "CreatedDateTime": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "GroupId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I tried to insert this through browser mapping are inserted correctly but when I tried it through elasticsearch java api I am following Exception

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.normalizer.my_normalizer.filter] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings]
```

This is the code I am using

```
    CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
    createIndexRequest.settings(settings.toString(), XContentType.JSON);
    createIndexRequest.mapping(typeName, mapping.toString(),XContentType.JSON);
    client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, header).isAcknowledged()
```

Elasticsearch 6.1.2.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Which version of the Java client API are you using? Could it be that you're not using the version 6.1.2?

Comment: I had using client 6.2.1, if I use client 6.1.2 I was not able to find create method For creation of mapping in client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, header).isAcknowledged()

Comment: could you suggest any alternative for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            //to put setting in the index   
             StringEntity settingEntity= new StringEntity(settings.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            int statuscode2 = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest("PUT", "/" + indexName , Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(), settingEntity).getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(200 == statuscode2) {
            }


            //to put mapping in the index
            StringEntity mappingEntity = new StringEntity(mapping.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            int statuscode3 = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest("PUT", "/" + indexName + "/" + typeName + "/" + "_mapping", Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(), mappingEntity).getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(200 == statuscode3) {
            }
```